# Why no margin in FireFox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, margin

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18795563/BLOGDESIGNNEW/index.html
In FireFox, Why is there no margin on the left of the hgroup in the header? It works fine in Chrome and Safari. How do i make it work in FireFox?

Comment: Chrome and Safari use the same rendering engine, so it's not as if it'd be two versus one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the hgroup's default display setting is inline. Setting it to block will fix your problem with the margin.

```
#topheader hgroup {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a margin to me.

[image: Firefox4+Firebug]

Answer (score 0):

after inspecting the html code of your page, I figured out the following issue in `#topheader hgroup` css:

`overflow: visible:;` Remove the column from the end of visible. i.e. `overflow: visible;`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Firefox? Firefox4 DOES show the margin but FF3.x may not because it does not have built-in styles for the new HTML5 elements. You must add 'display:block' for proper rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Margin does not work in most case. and that is becaus it should calculate distance with elements outside. and this is dificult.

you should try padding instead of margin:

```
#topheader hgroup {
padding: 1em;
overflow: visible;
}
```

also change `:` to `;` ;)

this will work in every browsers.